# Script (AJAX or JS) does not work properly in IE8

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer-8

I have a js/ajax script at http://worldcitiesdatabase.info/test1/

I just received a complaint that it does not work properly in IE8.

Onchange seems to work, but then the next menu is not populated.

Can you please help me figure it out?

Thanks

Not sure what the problematic part of the code is. Here is my guess:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {//  code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {//                      code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            newList="";
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                    newList = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    m1.innerHTML=newList;
                    m1.disabled=false;
                }
                if (menuname=="showCountry")  {
                    var c1=document.getElementById('showRegion');
                    if (c1.options.length==2) {
                        if (c1.options[0].value=='NONE') {
                            c1.remove(0);
                            c1.value='0';
                            reloadmenu(c1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET",newFile+".php?q="+menuvalue,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: You should add the (potentially) problematic JS to your question.

Comment: Not sure if it's the right part of the code, but added what is responsible for ajax

Comment: I don't know if this is the cause, but you use many variables without declaring them first - `menuname`, `menuvalue`, `m1`, etc. Consequently these are defined in global scope, which may cause the `onreadystatechange` function not to work correctly. I suspect this shows up in IE8 only because it is somehow triggering extra events when you alter the select elements.

Comment: these values are defined earlier in the code

Comment: Even so, they are liable to cause problems if their values change in between the request being sent and the response being received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
m1.innerHTML=newList;
```

is the culprit because you use `innerHTML` to add `<option>`s to `<select>`. This is a known bug in IE8 - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/276228.

**Note:** You can run your test page in your Internet Explorer if you just open Developer Tools and run it in IE8 mode (see for example http://techathlon.com/internet-explorer-10-run-compatibility-mode/)